# An access query comparing the time part in a date field with values input in a form

Tags: date, ms-access

I have an access query with predicates (conditions) on a date/time column called start_time. The condition is on two form fields defined with "Format" as "short time". The problem is that this query does not give correct results.

```
SELECT event_cust.*
FROM event_cust
WHERE  Format([start_time],"hh:mm") 
BETWEEN [Forms]![CustEventRptForm]![FromHour] 
AND [Forms]![CustEventRptForm]![ToHour]
```

Also tried it using `Format([start_time], "short time") BETWEEN ...` - did not work either.

Do we need anything in addition to above code to get the correct results?

I have tested with literal values as shown below and I get correct results with that.

```
SELECT event_cust.*
FROM event_cust
WHERE  Format([start_time],"hh:mm") BETWEEN '10:00' AND '13:00'
```

Comment: Seems to be working this way now:

where  Int((start_time - int(start_time))*1440) between CDbl( [Forms]![CustEventRptForm]![FromHour])*1440 and CDbl( [Forms]![CustEventRptForm]![ToHour])*1440

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it's not interpreting the value from the form correctly.

Try adding quotes before and after the values:

```
SELECT event_cust.* 
FROM event_cust 
WHERE Format([start_time],"hh:mm") Between "" & [Forms]![CustEventRptForm]![FromHour] & "" 
   And "" & [Forms]![CustEventRptForm]![ToHour] & ""
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - this gave the same results unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string comparisons for date/times.

```
SELECT event_cust.*
FROM event_cust
WHERE  TimeValue([start_time]) >= CDate([Forms]![CustEventRptForm]![FromHour]) 
AND TimeValue([start_time]) <= CDate([Forms]![CustEventRptForm]![ToHour])
```

Comment: this one gave an error "This expression is typed incorrectly, or is too complex to be evaluated. for example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables.".....guess I need to check further. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Seems to work this way:

where  Int((start_time - int(start_time))*1440) between CDbl( [Forms]![CustEventRptForm]![FromHour])*1440 and CDbl( [Forms]![CustEventRptForm]![ToHour])*1440